# Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter 2.9

Tags: jmeter

Match count: 2

Match[1][0]=3Manisha

Match[1][1]=3

Match[1][2]=Manisha

Match[2][0]=4joe

Match[2][1]=4

Match[2][2]=joe

I want to extract  3 from Match[1][1]=3 and 4 from Match[2][1]=4, i mean to extract 34 and send 34 as parameter to the next request. How shall i accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) combination with [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener to see variable names of matches. Then refer them as `${test_g0}`, `${test_g1}`, etc.

Above variables assume `test` reference name in [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) Post Processor